# If there exist integers m and n such that am + bn =1 and c≠± 1, then c does not divide a or c does not divide b

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Prove that for all integers a, b, and c. If there exist integers m and n such that am + bn =1 and c cannot be equal to 1 or negative 1, then c does not divide a or c does not divide b.

This is the problem 2(d) in the section 1.6, page 60 of the book "A Transition to Advanced Mathematics, written by Smith/Eggen/St. Andre. 2014 Edition."

I would like that you give me your opinion about my proof. Thanks!

**Proof by Contradiction.** Suppose that c divides a, and c divides b. Then, a=ck and b=cj, for some integers k and j. Therefore, am+bn=1=ck+cj=c(k+j). Thus, k+j = 1/c. But this is a contradiction because k, j and c are integers and c cannot be equal to 1 or negative 1. **Q.E.D.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

am+bn=1=ck+cj=c(k+j) should be 
$$ am+bn=1=ckm+cjn=c(km+jn)=1$$

And your proof is valid.

Comment: Thanks! I did not notice that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The error that Tahir Imanov pointed out should be fixed. The only other thing I would suggest is to change the actual contradiction you derive. Once you get to $$1 = c(km+jn)$$

You can write

$$c \mid 1 \,\,\qquad\text{but} \qquad\,\, c \neq \pm 1$$

And this is a more direct contradiction.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

assume there exist m,n in Z such that 
am+bn=1   and c does not equal 1,-1 and c|a and c|b
a ck & b=ct
then am=ckm  &bn=ctn
so , am+an=c(km+tn)=1
since c does not equal 1
there is a contradiction

Comment: This seems like a rehash of the OP's proof.